# How to retrieve list of objects in rails from an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an array with the elements [5,7,8,13]. These elements get dynamically generated based on a user’s action…they’re not hardcoded in.

I have a Product table. I would like to store the list of objects that have product id’s referenced in the array above.

```
@products = Product.where(id = those in the array)
```

I’m not sure how to do this. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do

```
ids = [5,7,8,13]
@products = Product.where(id: ids)
```